# How can I test a stove burner switch?

Tags: switch, range

How to test right front burner switch of JennAir JES9900BAS and switch is WPW10185286. I would like to have wiring diagram and instructions about how to test this switch. This is to make sure it is bad before I make purchase new one. my right front element of JennAir JES9900BAS range is not working. I was told that it could be switch or it could be element which could have gone bad. So before buying either switch or dual burner element, I am trying to check if switch is bad or it is good. I have done following test on suggestion of one of my friend

with switch not installed  and it is in "on" position. used ohm 200 setting on digital multimeter.

(A) line 1 to H1 : OHM reading is there.

(B) line 2 to H2A : no reading

(C) line 2  to H2B : no reading

I am not sure about wiring diagram, so may be I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome. Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also, take the [tour] when you get a chance.

Comment: Fault finding on specific models of electrical devices is more the domain of youtube than this forum.  But without getting into minute details of your model ... with the switch on and the leads disconnected from the element is there voltage on the leads?  Is it possible to mix and match switches and elements to determine which one is bad?

Comment: @jay613  I have to politely disagree with the YouTube reference.  Lots of ppl who think they  know what they're doing but don't and can give really dangerous advice. I've viewed some of the vids and I think, "are you crazy?"  What I like about Stack Exchange is that there are many qualified experts and that answers and comments get "peer reviewed".  If there are any stupid or dangerous answers or comments posted, they usually get killed off (closed) pretty quickly.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I agree that the quality on SE is higher on average than on youtube and that there is some complete nonsense on youtube, for sure.  But there is some truly awesome, fantastic, helpful content on youtube too that is highly tutorial and not constrained to the Q&A format here.   And when it comes to step-by-step guides to disassembling and diagnosing specific models of appliance, youtube is the gold standard for DIY --- EVEN THOUGH as you say, there is also a lot of total crap and nonsense there. Saying SE is better than youtube is almost like saying it's better than the internet.

Comment: @jay613  I generally agree with you, but on youtube you have to sift thru a bunch of vids to find the good ones, and then you need to know enough to recognize the good ones. LOL.  Here on SE, most of the stuff posted is good and with experts responding seems to be more efficient and higher quality.   Thanks  for your comments.